# How to Focus on a TextBlock in XAML WPF with keyboard (for example with tab) in a Grid view?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, textblock

I have a textblock which has a binding path with a converter, but I am unable to operate that with tab button. Textblock has an Onclick property which opens another page. I want to open that screen with keyboard. Kindly help!

I tried Keyboard Focusable in  and also Focusable=On but its not working

Comment: Have a look here about the `TabIndex` property: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.control.tabindex?view=windowsdesktop-8.0

Comment: @MarioVernari TaxIndex is a button property. Is there an equivalent property to select TextBlocks/Focus it with tab?

Comment: not exactly: `TabIndex` is a `Control` property, which is a base class for both `Button` and `TextBox`, as well as many others. However, `TextBlock` is just a presentation element, not accepting any input, thus the `TabIndex` has no sense. Instead of the `TextBlock`, you should switch to the `TextBox` (maybe by setting its `IsReadOnly` property).

Comment: My 2 cents: If it is clickable, and induces an action, it should be a button. You can still style it the way you want, but the element used should be chosen according to the functionality, not the visual representation.

Answer (score 3):

You could (should!) use a `Button` and make it look like a `TextBlock`:

```
<Button Click="Button_Click">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <TextBlock Text="Focus me!" />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

The above element can be both keyboard focused and clicked and still looks like a `TextBlock`.

Remember that WPF controls are lookless which means that a control's behavior is independent from its appearance.

Comment: Replacing the TextBlock with a ContentPresenter yields the same effect except that the Button can handle any object as its content as usual. Using a TextBlock limits the use cases of such a button. The key point here is to override the default ControlTemplate as this will automatically remove the default visual behavior of the control (e.g. mouse hover effects etc.).